# Adding new key-value pair into json using karate

Tags: karate

My payload looks like this :

```
{
  "override_source": "DS",
  "property_code": "0078099",
  "stay_date": "2018-11-26T00:00:00.000000",
  "sku_prices": [
  ],
  "persistent_override": false
}
```

There is an array dblist `["2","3"]` , it would consists of numbers from 1 to 4. Based on the elements present in the list, I want to add key-values `{"sku_price":"1500","sku_code":"2"}` to my payload. I am using the following code :

```
* eval if(contains("3",dblist)) karate.set('pushRatesFromDS.sku_prices[]','{ "sku_price": "1500","sku_code":"3" }')
```

When I execute my feature file, I do not get any errors but, key-values are not added to my payload. However if I move this code to a new feature file and call it, key-value pairs get added to my payload. The code in my new feature file looks like : `* set pushRatesFromDS.sku_prices[] = { "sku_price": "1500","sku_code":"2" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
* def foo =
"""
{
  "override_source": "DS",
  "property_code": "0078099",
  "stay_date": "2018-11-26T00:00:00.000000",
  "sku_prices": [
  ],
  "persistent_override": false
}
"""
* eval karate.set('foo', '$.sku_prices[]', { foo: 'bar' })
```