# Karate - Is there a way to add a new json key/value pair to an existing JSON object where the key is the same and values are different?

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

I am a newbie at both JavaScript and Karate. This may not be a Karate centric question per se, however, I am wondering if the solution can be done in Karate natively by any chance.

I have looked at existing questions on here but they don't seem to work likely due to my unique input. This answer looked promising, but it didn't work out for me: [Adding new key-value pair into json using karate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554411/adding-new-key-value-pair-into-json-using-karate)

I have a JAVA method that produces a payload consisting of a JSON object (which has a secondary json object in it) for a POST call. The payload looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "keyId": "s123",
    "clientId": "c0909",
    "regionInfo": {
      "geoTag": "3s98d238",
      "locationId": 32
    }
  }
]
```

Now I am doing a test where I have to insert a bogus key/value pair into the payload and make sure it is ignored in the POST call itself and we return a 200. I have tried using karate.merge and karate.append, but they have not worked thus far.

The key value pair looks like this:

`{'bogusfield': 'ABC', 'bogusfield': '123', 'bogusfield': 'abc123', 'bogusfield': 'abc123!$%'}`

So in total, there will be four POST calls , each with a different value from above .Is ttherea way to get this done? I apologize if I missed on giving any crucial details/and/or if this too newb of a question. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that makes 4 requests with the payload edits you want which should get you on your way:

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* path 'anything'
* def body = { foo: 'bar' }
* body.bogusField = bogusValue
* request body
* method post

Examples:
| bogusValue |
| ABC        |
| 123        |
| abc123     |
| abc123!$%  |
```

Comment: If I am reading your solution correctly, you are proposing a field besides the actual payload called "body" and sending these requests in, correct? I have done something exactly similar, however, the requirements are that this "bogus field" MUST be part of the actual payload. So in my original post, the following must happen:
```
[
  {
    "keyId": "s123",
    "clientId": "c0909",
    "bogusField": abc"
    "regionInfo": {
      "geoTag": "3s98d238",
      "locationId": 32
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I apologize for commenting on a closed question, but I saw your response somewhere else regarding using karate.set. It does work for me if I use one value. But since I have multiple values for the same key where each value needs to be included in a payload call- totaling in four, can karate.set still be used somehow?