# Karate - Can Karate.set be used to insert a new key with multiple values and the values be iterated on for POST call?

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, karate

I am a newbie at both JavaScript and Karate. This may not be a Karate centric question per se, however, I am wondering if the solution can be done in Karate natively by any chance.

I have an array of JSON objects where I need to include a key with multiple values. This array of JSON objects will act as the "payload" for a POST call. The JSON object looks like:

```
[
  {
    "keyId": "s123",
    "clientId": "c0909",
    "regionInfo": {
      "geoTag": "3s98d238",
      "locationId": 32
    }
  }
]
```

Now I am doing a test where I have to insert a bogus key/value pair into the payload and make sure it is ignored in the POST call itself and we return a 200. The bogus field will look like:

```
{'bogusfield': 'ABC', 'bogusfield': '123', 'bogusfield': 'abc123', 'bogusfield': 'abc123!$%'}
```

My scenario calling file looks like this:

```
    @sendingPostRequest
    Scenario: Sending POST request
        Given url sampleUrl
        And path randomParams
        And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        And request payload
        When method POST
        *response verification happens here*
```

I have a table set up where I have a column solely dedicated for "payload". The table looks like this:

```
Date  | Payload          | Status |
today |bogusFieldPayload | 200    | // 'ABC' bogus field (included in the legitimate payload).
today |bogusFieldPayload | 200    | // '123' bogus field (included in the legitimate payload).
today |bogusFieldPayload | 200    | // 'abc123' bogus field (included in the legitimate payload).
today |bogusFieldPayload | 200    | // 'abc123!$%' bogus field (included in the legitimate payload).
```

I also considered adding an "extra payload" field in the runner file (And request karate.get 'extraPayload') and it worked beautifully as an extra column in the table. However, the bogus field has to be a PART of the actual payload and not an extra field after it.

My apologies about the length of the question and for any unclear parts.

Comment: in my opinion this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052748/143475 - I have no idea why `karate.set()` has to come into the picture. so I pass for now. if you want me to look at this later - please please re-write your question so that it is a complete `Scenario Outline` instead of us having to guess what arrays you are using where. your question is super confusing in multiple ways

Comment: @PeterThomas please review, I have added more details.

Comment: no I don't see a difference. did you try running the answer I posted to your duplicate question ? it sends a json POST and it adds one key from your data-table. so please use that question as a starting point and help me understand what EXTRA you need. please don't side-track me with arrays and random tables

Comment: @PeterThomas No, I haven't tried your solution in the other question, because when I asked for clarification, you said something like: "...just try what I suggested first then ask questions". I do appreciate your time in reading and responding.

Comment: no, you don't ;)